# Python module returning errors in bash but not from IDLE

Tags: python, macos, python-import, python-idle, fuzzywuzzy

I'm a newbie programmer posting here for the first time. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated! I am working on a project that compares the contents of, say test.csv to ref.csv (both single columns containing strings of 3-4 words) and assigns a score to each string from test.csv based its similarity to the most similar string in ref.csv. I am using the [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) string matching module to assign the similarity score.

The following code snippet takes the two input files, converts them into arrays, and prints out the arrays:

```
import csv

# Load text matching module
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process


# Import reference and test lists and assign to variables
ref_doc = csv.reader(open('ref.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
test_doc = csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=",", quotechar='|')

# Define the arrays into which to load these lists
ref = []
test = []

# Assign the reference and test docs to arrays
for row in ref_doc:
    ref.append(row)

for row in test_doc:
    test.append(row)

# Print the arrays to make sure this all worked properly
# before we procede to run matching operations on the arrays
print ref, "\n\n\n", test
```

The problem is that this script works as expected when I run it in IDLE, but returns the following error when I call it from bash:

```
['one', 'two']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csvimport_orig.py", line 4, in <module>
    from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py", line 32, in <module>
    import utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy/utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    table_from=string.punctuation+string.ascii_uppercase
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'punctuation'
```

Is there something I need to configure in bash for this to work properly? Or is there something fundamentally wrong that IDLE is not catching? For simplicity's sake, I don't call the fuzzywuzzy module in this snippet, but it works as expected in IDLE.

Eventually, I'd like to use [pylevenshtein](http://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/) but am trying to see if my use for this script has value before I put the extra time in making that work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly you have a module called `string.py` which is being loaded instead of the stdlib's `string.py` module.

You can confirm this by adding the lines

```
import string
print string
```

to your `csvimport_orig.py` program.  This *should* show something like

```
<module 'string' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/string.pyc'>
```

[I'm on linux at the moment, so the location is different and you should see the usual `/Library/Frameworks/etc.` equivalent.]  What it will probably show instead is

```
<module 'string' from 'string.py'>
```

or, instead of `string.py`, wherever your conflicting library is.  Rename your `string.py` module.

Comment: You called it. I had a string.py file in the same directory as my script, this was where the ['one', 'two'] in my error message was coming from. Renamed the file and now the script works as expected. Thank you.